# How to loop a conditional loop more efficiently using Polars?

Tags: performance, for-loop, if-statement, vectorization, python-polars

I am kind of reposting this question because I am still looking for a faster implementation (now with polars). I have improved the speed around 10x using polars instead of pandas. However, I need a more efficient way to run this function.
The problem is that I have two nested for-loops with a condition on the second one (conditional on another df).

*The set up is the same.*  I have a **dataset** with multiple ids, values, and dates (large T, large N). Additionally, there are other datasets, **SB_dates** with random dates (in blocks) and **newBL**, a boolean array matrix of the same size as **SB_dates**.

For each new block, I need to select 5 (n) random ids and calculate the average values on that date. If it's not a new block, I should retain the same random ids that were previously selected.

Using polars, I have have coded the function like this, with **data** and **SB_dates** as pl.DataFrames.

```
def get_mean_chrono_polars(data, SB_dates, newBL, n=5):
    n_rows, n_columns = SB_dates.shape
    df_sb = pl.DataFrame()

    for col in range(n_columns):
        date_column = pl.DataFrame( SB_dates[:, col])
        newBL_column = newBL[:, col]
        mean_values_col = []

        for i in range(n_rows):                        
            filter_ids=(data
                             .select(pl.col("date",'values','ids'))
                             .filter(pl.col("date") == date_column[i,:]))            
            if newBL_column[i]:
                random_ids=filter_ids.select(pl.col("ids").shuffle(seed=1)).limit(n)

            selected_ids_df = (
                filter_ids
                .select(pl.col("date", 'values', 'ids'))
                .filter(pl.col('ids').is_in(random_ids['ids']))
            )
            
            mean_values = selected_ids_df['values'].mean()
            mean_values_col.append(mean_values)
        mean_values_col=pl.Series(str(col),mean_values_col)        
        df_sb=df_sb.hstack([mean_values_col])
    return df_sb


r=get_mean_chrono_polars(data, SB_dates, newBL, n=5)
```

**The data**

```
import polars as pl
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
     
n_rows = 1000  # You can adjust this as needed
start_date = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime(2023, 12, 31)

dates = [
    start_date + timedelta(days=random.randint(0, (end_date - start_date).days))
    for _ in range(n_rows)
]

unique_ids = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(n_rows)]
returns = [random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01) for _ in range(n_rows)]
data = pl.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'values': returns, 'ids': unique_ids})
data=data.with_columns(date=pl.col("date").dt.month_end())
```

Sorry again for the long post.
Here is the link to the original post: [Speeding up by removing col and row for-loops (loop with condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77185984/speeding-up-by-removing-col-and-row-for-loops-loop-with-condition)

Comment: I had to add `.item()` to `date_column[i,:]` to get rid of a `ValueError` but then `selected_stocks_df` isn't defined. Can you add an example of `selected_stocks_df` to make the code runnable? (Along with the code for `SB_dates` and `newBL` as opposed to their repr.)

Comment: Sorry for that! I've edited the question with the complete DGP and implementable code. The function 'SB' is a modified Stationary Bootstrap, which not only resamples data but also identifies the start of each block as 'newBL.' For more details: https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bootstrap/timeseries-bootstraps.html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- (See comments below, thank you to @jqurious) - `melt`ing the two static dataframes, `SB_dates` and `newBL`, gives you all the data in column1, column2..., order, which is exactly what is needed for this problem to eliminate the first loop. (Even if not, a `sort` could have been done to get it in this order.) Each element is uniquely identified by `row_nr` and the `variable` column (renamed to `col`) in this newly reshaped DataFrame.
- A left join (which maintains the order of the left DataFrame) of this static dataframe with the main `data` can do all the `filter_ids = ...` step.
- A `group_by` further readies "choose `n` random IDs on that day" step.
- With `maintain_order=True`, we further maintain the original order from the left join, and thus each element of the final returned DataFrame will correctly correspond to each element of `SB_dates` and `newBL`.
- A `pl.when` can be used in the `agg`regation to null out any unneeded calculations.
- Note also we only need the `values` after the `agg`regation, the `ids` were just needed to pair with the corresponding `values` in the `sample`. Now we discard everything but the `values`.
- Unnesting the `values` list with `list.to_struct`, then `unnest` is needed to avoid lists of nulls / struct of nulls - just a `null` per new column if `newBL` is `False`.
- Each mean is then calculated and a `strategy` of `forward` is used on `fill_nulls` at this time.

That gets you the `mean_val`s in a one-column dataframe, which can optionally be `reshape`d back into the original `SB_dates` shape if desired.

```py
import polars as pl
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

n_rows = 100000
start_date = date(2000, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2023, 12, 31)

random.seed(1)

# Generate data
dates = [
    start_date + timedelta(days=random.randint(0, (end_date - start_date).days))
    for _ in range(n_rows)
]
sb_dates = [
    [
        start_date + timedelta(days=random.randint(0, (end_date - start_date).days))
        for _ in range(20)
    ]
    for _ in range(6)
]
returns = [random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01) for _ in range(n_rows)]
ids = random.sample(range(n_rows * 1000), n_rows)

# Create a Polars DataFrame
data = pl.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'values': returns, 'ids': ids})

sb_data = pl.DataFrame({f'bd{i}': sb_dates[i] for i in range(6)}).with_columns(
    (pl.all().dt.month_end())
)
blnew_data = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        f'bn{i}': [random.random() < 0.5 if j else True for j in range(20)]
        for i in range(6)
    }
)


def get_mean_chrono_polars(data, SB_dates, newBL, n=5):
    static_data = (
        sb_data.with_row_count()
        .melt('row_nr', variable_name='col', value_name='date')
        .with_columns(blnew_data.melt().select(bl='value'))
    )

    return (
        static_data.join(data, on='date', how='left')
        .group_by('row_nr', 'col', maintain_order=True)
        .agg(pl.when(pl.col('bl')).then(pl.col('ids', 'values').sample(n)))
        .select(
            pl.col('values').list.to_struct(
                n_field_strategy='max_width',
                fields=[f'val{j}' for j in range(n)],
                upper_bound=n,
            ),
        )
        .unnest('values')
        .select(
            mean_val=(pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all()) / n)
            .fill_null(strategy='forward')
        # steps from this point are optional
            .reshape(SB_dates.shape)
            .list.to_struct(
                n_field_strategy='max_width',
                fields=[f'{j}' for j in range(len(SB_dates.columns))],
                upper_bound=len(SB_dates.columns),
            )
        )
        .unnest('mean_val')
    )

get_mean_chrono_polars(data, sb_data, blnew_data)
```

Comment: My initial thought was perhaps melt then the left join would be a starting point to do it without loops: `sb_data.with_row_count().melt('row_nr', variable_name='col', value_name='date').with_columns(blnew_data.melt().select(bl = 'value'))` - Haven't investigated further yet so not sure if it complicates things or not.

Comment: @Wayoshi This new approach seems to do the job much faster. Thank you for all the details. However,  I can't retrieve the columns when `newBL` is set to `False` after using `pl.agg(pl.when`.   PS. I just modified the `selectors` part to prevent repeated ones when the number of columns exceeds 10. Thank you again!

Comment: Yeah, I took some liberties on defining my versions of `SB_dates` and `newBL` (started writing the answer when you were editing the original post), so whatever tweaks. I think the main points are how the `join` (or `melt` as jqurious suggests), only filling nulls at the end, etc., really cuts the work down.

Comment: Indeed, an extra `join` and a `melt` worked. Thanks to both.

Comment: Great, I edited the answer just for completeness at this point.